# how do i solve the : An error occurred during auto-correction in vscode

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code

I'm asking for your help, I'm trying to identify my ruby code in vscode, but when I give shft+alt+f to identify, it gives this error : An error occurred during auto-correction, I've tried everything, I hope someone can help me!

I've tried uninstalling and installing rubocop from vscode, I've tried reinstalling ruby on my machine and nothing has worked...